# Nested replace of strings with double quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

In Logic Apps I have this function which replaces double double quotes with a zero for some strings.
How can I replicate this in Javascript?

```js
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(body('HTTP_2'),'"PR_RENT":""','"PR_RENT":0'),'"PR_ID":""','"PR_ID":0'),'"PR_USUM":""','"PR_USUM":0'),'"PR_LEAS":""','"PR_LEAS":0'),'"PR_USER8":""','"PR_USER8":0')
```

I tried this code.

````
```
var json = workflowContext.actions.HTTP_2.outputs.body
if (json.PR_RENT=="\"\"")
{
json.PR_RENT=0
}
if (json.PR_ID=="\"\"")
{
json.PR_ID=0
}
if (json.PR_USUM=="\"\"")
{
json.PR_USUM=0
}
if (json.PR_LEAS=="\"\"")
{
json.PR_LEAS=0
}
if (json.PR_USER8=="\"\"")
{
json.PR_USER8=0
}
return json;
```
````

and got error messages like this for all the affected fields.

````
```[
 {
 "message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String.",
 "lineNumber": 0,
 "linePosition": 0,
 "path": "Payload[0].PR_USER8",
 "value": "",
 "schemaId": "#/properties/Payload/items/properties/PR_USER8",
 "errorType": "type",
 "childErrors": []
 },
 ,
 {
 "message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String.",
 "lineNumber": 0,
 "linePosition": 0,
 "path": "Payload[2].PR_RENT",
 "value": "",
 "schemaId": "#/properties/Payload/items/properties/PR_RENT",
 "errorType": "type",
 "childErrors": []
  }
]
````

````
Here is some of my JSON code

```{"Payload":[{"RLS_GROUP":"","PR_SNAM":"700063","PR_OWN":"qqq","PR_REF":"","PR_NAME":"Bqqq12","PR_ADD1":"qqq","PR_ADD2":"INDUSTRIAL ESTATE","PR_ADD3":"23  INDUSTRIAL ESTATE","PR_ADD4":"yyy","PR_ADD5":"","PR_ADD6":"GB","PR_POST":"WQDQWD","PR_TEL":"23213","PR_TELX":"21312312","PR_FAX":"","PR_CONT":"","PR_NUNIT":"","PR_INT":"","PR_TENR":"LEASED","PR_QDAY":"","PR_CLSS":"","PR_DRCT":"Closing","PR_AGENT":"","PR_NOWN":"","PR_BOWN":"","PR_SOL":"","PR_HSTT":"","PR_HEND":"","PR_HAMT":"","PR_PFREQ":"","PR_NTENT":"","PR_NFLR":"","PR_GRA":"","PR_WATER":"","PR_RATVAL":"","PR_RTCT":"","PR_SCHG":"","PR_OCHG":"","PR_GFA":"","PR_ZONEA":"","PR_ZONEB":"","PR_ZONEC":"","PR_UPDATE":"","PR_UTIME":"","PR_UUSER":"","PR_HIST":"","PR_TAXYN":"","PR_TAX":"","PR_START":"","PR_END":"","PR_FREQ":"","PR_QTR":"","PR_NDUE":"","PR_TAXRUN":"","PR_OUTLET":"","PR_INLET":"","PR_VAL":"","PR_CST":"","PR_FRWA":"","PR_FRWB":"","PR_PRINT":"","PR_NL":"","PR_CURRS":"","PR_NEXTS":"","PR_VAT":"D","PR_USER":"","PR_VQDAY":"","PR_OBS1":"STANDARD NORTH","PR_TYPE":"Property","PR_VATDATE":"","PR_FUTHER":"","PR_RESTEN":"","PR_CAPGOODS":"","PR_INSEE":"","PR_CURR":"","PR_AQDATE":"20190917","PR_USER1":"Office","PR_USER2":"Yes","PR_USER3":"","PR_USER4":"","PR_USER5":"20190917","PR_USER6":"","PR_USER7":"","PR_USER8":0,"PR_USER9":"","PR_USER10":"","PR_OBS2":"","PR_OBS3":"","PR_OBS4":"","PR_OBS5":"","PR_OBS6":"","PR_OBS7":"UK","PR_OBS8":"","PR_OBS9":"","PR_SOLD":"0","PR_DATESOLD":"20200917","PR_LAND":"","PR_LANDUM":"","PR_FREE":"","PR_ID":0,"PR_BTYP":"F","PR_LEAS":0,"PR_RENT":999999,"PR_USUM":0,"PR_FBUI":0,"PR_DREN":"","PR_USRC":"","PR_RSRC":"","PR_LSRC":"","PR_ELSR":"","PR_EGRS":"","PR_PROR":"","PR_BSTA":"","PR_LNAM":"123123213","PR_SITE":"","PR_REGION":"","PR_DESC":""}]}
````

I have to do this because the API is returning "" for integer fields instead of zero when there is no value.

I tried this code

```
var json = workflowContext.actions.HTTP_2.outputs.body;
json.Payload[0].RLS_GROUP='Test';
json.Payload[0].PR_REF=123;
return json;
```

and got this message

```
InlineCodeScriptRuntimeFailure. The inline code action 'JavaScriptCode' 
execution failed, with error 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'.
```

Also, my Javascript action screen looks a bit different to yours.

[image]

I tried this code.  It seems to have worked for the first example, but not all examples.  Perhaps the data contains a space before the double double quotes.
How do I iterate through all payload elements?

```
var jsonString = workflowContext.actions.HTTP_2.outputs.body;
const json =JSON.parse(jsonString);
const dic = json['Payload'][0];
const checkFields = ['PR_RENT','PR_ID','PR_USUM','PR_LEAS','PR_USER8'];
checkFields.forEach(field=>{
    console.log(dic[field]); 
    if(dic[field]=='""')
    {
        dic[field]=0;
        console.log(field);
    }
}
);
return json;
```

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: I submitted my own answer, but also voted yours up.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If that could work you could mark it as the answer to help other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This treats the json as a string and not an array.

````
json=json.replace(/"PR_USER8":""/g,'"PR_USER8":0').replace(/"PR_RENT":""/g,'"PR_RENT":0').replace(/"PR_ID":""/g,'"PR_ID":0').replace(/"PR_USUM":""/g,'"PR_USUM":0').replace(/"PR_LEAS":""/g,'"PR_LEAS":0');
return json;```

I think this is better as it treats the json as an object not a string.

    ```
    var jsonString = workflowContext.actions.HTTP_2.outputs.body;
const json =JSON.parse(jsonString);
const ret =[];

const dic = json['Payload'];
const checkFields = ['PR_RENT','PR_ID','PR_USUM','PR_LEAS','PR_USER8'];
for(i in json['Payload'])
{


checkFields.forEach(field=>{
     if(json.Payload[i][field]=="")
    {
        json.Payload[i][field]=0;
       // console.log(field);
    }
}

);
}

return json;
    ```
````

Comment: When I look at the inputs for the function, it just gives me the Javascript code rather than the results of the previous http2 action  {
    "code": "var json = workflowContext.actions.HTTP_2.outputs.body;\r\njson.Payload[0].RLS_Group=\"testvalue\";\r\njson.Payload[0].PR_SNAM=12;\r\nreturn json;\r\n"
}

Comment: It shows no output, but your examples work.  Could the problem be due to the JSON being more than 1024 characters though nowhere near 50mb?  I also wonder if it treats the JSON as a string rather than a JSON object.

Comment: When I set an object variable to the result of my JSON it fails with this message.    BadRequest. The variable 'TestVariableForInlineCode' of type 'Object' cannot be initialized or updated with value '{"Payload":     With a string variable it is OK.

Comment: After test, I think I find the problem. I test with postman, I believe your `Content-Type` is not `application/json`, you could check it in the HTTP action. If that use `JSON.parse()` to parse it to json object or change the `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

Comment: `I also wonder if it treats the JSON as a string rather than a JSON object.`  This is up to your action output content-type.

Comment: If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I changed HTTP2 from text/json to application/json with no change.  How do I select the action output content type?

Comment: If you could not change the content-type,did you try JSON.parse()?

Comment: And actually, I don't think you change the content-type in the http action would change the type. The type is up to the the url server response type. I tried if the server response the text, change the type to application/json in the http action, it's still text. So change the server response header or in the inline code use `JSON.parse()` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JavaScript to manage the json, just set the value directly. You could refer to my actions as the below pic show. The expression would be like `json.key=value;`

[image]

**Update**: I test with the array json it could work, you need to point the index. If not please provide more information.

[image]