# Nested replace of strings with double quotes in Javascript - Part 2

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In Logic Apps I have this function which replaces double double quotes with a zero for some strings.
How can I replicate this in Javascript?

````
```javascript
 replace(replace(replace(replace
 (replace(body('HTTP_2'),'"PR_RENT":""','"PR_RENT":0'), 
 '"PR_ID":""','"PR_ID":0'),'"PR_USUM":""','"PR_USUM":0'),'"PR_LEAS":""','"PR_LEAS":0'),
'"PR_USER8":""','"PR_USER8":0')
 ```
````

This question has been answered [here] ([Nested replace of strings with double quotes in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161063/nested-replace-of-strings-with-double-quotes-in-javascript)).  The problem is that this solution required an Integration Account which costs quite a bit of money.  Is there any way to do this without an Integration Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the solution of javascript with integration account, we can also add azure function in logic app and write the js code in azure function to meet your requirements. Please refer to the steps below:

1. Create an azure function app in azure portal by referring this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal). But this tutorial is creating .net function, we need to create nodejs function, so you should select "Node.js" as "Runtime stack".
   [image]

In "Hosting" tab, you can choose "Consumption" as "Plan type".
[image]

Consumption plan can help us save money, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan) to know the cost of azure function.

2. After creating the azure function app, please go to your function app and create a function. Refer to the screenshot below and choose "HTTP trigger" in the next step.
   [image]
3. Put the js code to HttpTrigger function.
   [image]
4. Then we come back to logic app, create "Azure Functions" connector by referring this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#create-functions-inside-logic-apps), choose the httptrigger function which you created just now.
5. Provide your json data as the request body to azure function action.(I have stored your json data as a variable named "data").
   [image]
6. Run the logic app, get the result which we expect.
   [image]

The whole output json data show as below:

```
{
  "Payload": [
    {
      "RLS_GROUP": "",
      "PR_SNAM": "700063",
      "PR_OWN": "qqq",
      "PR_REF": "",
      "PR_NAME": "Bqqq12",
      "PR_ADD1": "qqq",
      "PR_ADD2": "INDUSTRIAL ESTATE",
      "PR_ADD3": "23  INDUSTRIAL ESTATE",
      "PR_ADD4": "yyy",
      "PR_ADD5": "",
      "PR_ADD6": "GB",
      "PR_POST": "WQDQWD",
      "PR_TEL": "23213",
      "PR_TELX": "21312312",
      "PR_FAX": "",
      "PR_CONT": "",
      "PR_NUNIT": "",
      "PR_INT": "",
      "PR_TENR": "LEASED",
      "PR_QDAY": "",
      "PR_CLSS": "",
      "PR_DRCT": "Closing",
      "PR_AGENT": "",
      "PR_NOWN": "",
      "PR_BOWN": "",
      "PR_SOL": "",
      "PR_HSTT": "",
      "PR_HEND": "",
      "PR_HAMT": "",
      "PR_PFREQ": "",
      "PR_NTENT": "",
      "PR_NFLR": "",
      "PR_GRA": "",
      "PR_WATER": "",
      "PR_RATVAL": "",
      "PR_RTCT": "",
      "PR_SCHG": "",
      "PR_OCHG": "",
      "PR_GFA": "",
      "PR_ZONEA": "",
      "PR_ZONEB": "",
      "PR_ZONEC": "",
      "PR_UPDATE": "",
      "PR_UTIME": "",
      "PR_UUSER": "",
      "PR_HIST": "",
      "PR_TAXYN": "",
      "PR_TAX": "",
      "PR_START": "",
      "PR_END": "",
      "PR_FREQ": "",
      "PR_QTR": "",
      "PR_NDUE": "",
      "PR_TAXRUN": "",
      "PR_OUTLET": "",
      "PR_INLET": "",
      "PR_VAL": "",
      "PR_CST": "",
      "PR_FRWA": "",
      "PR_FRWB": "",
      "PR_PRINT": "",
      "PR_NL": "",
      "PR_CURRS": "",
      "PR_NEXTS": "",
      "PR_VAT": "D",
      "PR_USER": "",
      "PR_VQDAY": "",
      "PR_OBS1": "STANDARD NORTH",
      "PR_TYPE": "Property",
      "PR_VATDATE": "",
      "PR_FUTHER": "",
      "PR_RESTEN": "",
      "PR_CAPGOODS": "",
      "PR_INSEE": "",
      "PR_CURR": "",
      "PR_AQDATE": "20190917",
      "PR_USER1": "Office",
      "PR_USER2": "Yes",
      "PR_USER3": "",
      "PR_USER4": "",
      "PR_USER5": "20190917",
      "PR_USER6": "",
      "PR_USER7": "",
      "PR_USER8": 0,
      "PR_USER9": "",
      "PR_USER10": "",
      "PR_OBS2": "",
      "PR_OBS3": "",
      "PR_OBS4": "",
      "PR_OBS5": "",
      "PR_OBS6": "",
      "PR_OBS7": "UK",
      "PR_OBS8": "",
      "PR_OBS9": "",
      "PR_SOLD": "0",
      "PR_DATESOLD": "20200917",
      "PR_LAND": "",
      "PR_LANDUM": "",
      "PR_FREE": "",
      "PR_ID": 0,
      "PR_BTYP": "F",
      "PR_LEAS": 0,
      "PR_RENT": 0,
      "PR_USUM": 0,
      "PR_FBUI": 0,
      "PR_DREN": "",
      "PR_USRC": "",
      "PR_RSRC": "",
      "PR_LSRC": "",
      "PR_ELSR": "",
      "PR_EGRS": "",
      "PR_PROR": "",
      "PR_BSTA": "",
      "PR_LNAM": "123123213",
      "PR_SITE": "",
      "PR_REGION": "",
      "PR_DESC": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

The five fields have been replaced with 0.

The advantage of this solution is the consumption plan cost money only when your functions are running. I think it will be cheaper than integration account.